# Match 2 dataframes using a 3rd dataframe and apply a function in R

Tags: r, match, lookup, correlation

I've two dfs (d1 and d2). I have to apply a correlation function to each time series after matching the Product IDs from a third data frame (m, in this example). It can be a one-to-many match. For example, "c" is linked to both "C" and "D". So, for "A"-"a", cor function would be applied to (1,2) from d1 and (50,20) from d2. How do we automate this process? Any sort of help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
    #Reproducible Example 
    d1 <- data.frame(ProductID1 = c("A","B","C","D"), 
    Aug16 = c(1,2,3,4), Sep16 = c(2,3,4,4))

     d2 <- data.frame(ProductID2 = c("a","b","c"), 
   Aug16 = c(50,20,30), Sep16 = c(20,40,40))

    m <- data.frame(ProductID1 = c("A","B","C","D"),
    ProductID2 = c("a","b","c","c"))


     # Look up the value of A in dataframe m, the value is "a". 
   #Find "a" in dataframe d2. Apply cor() to A's time series and a's time series.


    # Output should look like this. I can put the correlation values(-0.1285341, etc.) in a matrix.    

     # A matched with a, apply cor function
    cor(as.numeric(d1[1,2:3]),as.numeric(d2[1,2:3]))
       [1] -0.1285341
    # B matched with b, apply cor function
    cor(as.numeric(d1[2,2:3]),as.numeric(d2[2,2:3]))
       [1] 0.8808123
    # C matched with c, apply cor function
    cor(as.numeric(d1[3,2:3]),as.numeric(d2[3,2:3]))
       [1] -1
    # D matched with c, apply cor function
    cor(as.numeric(d1[4,2:3]),as.numeric(d2[3,2:3]))
       [1] NA
```

Comment: Can you update your post with expected output ?

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah, sorry, I've done that now. Does that help? Thanks!

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking. Updating a question with a dataframe / list of what you want the output to look like wold be helpful

Comment: In this example, the correlation is going to be calculated on columns with four rows, due matching?

Comment: Hi @s_t, correlation on rows! The matching has to be automated. I can see from dataframe "m" that "A" is linked to "a", but I want R to automatically find the match and apply cor() to the two time series ("a" and "A").

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but perhaps this is what you are looking for (but does not exactly matchthe given desired output)..

```
myFunction <- function(x,y){
  subset_d1 <- d1[ d1$ProductID1 == x, ]
  subset_d2 <- d2[ d2$ProductID2 == y, ]
  return( cor( as.numeric( subset_d1 ), as.numeric( subset_d2 ) ) )
}

mapply( myFunction, m$ProductID1, m$ProductID2, SIMPLIFY = TRUE )
```

**output**

```
[1] -0.1285341  0.8808123  0.7088739         NA
```

with a warning for the fourth row of m... `standard deviation is zero` (so cor --> NA )

Comment: Hello @Wimpel thank you very much for the answer! I ran my code again and the last value is indeed NA.